# How to write program.cs file for .NET 6 Library Project? - getting error "Program using top-level statements must be an executable"

Tags: c#, dll, startup, .net-6.0

I keep all the data related classes, interfaces, configurations, etc in a separate library project so it can easily be reused for any other project I need (API, WebAssembly, Mobile, Server Pages, etc..)

I have converted all the projects from the solution to .NET6. They all work and build, as the did before, except for the data library which is giving me the following error: `Program using top-level statements must be an executable.`

How do I write the new .NET 6 `Program.cs` file for a .NET 6 library?

The new `Program.cs` file that is not working:

```
using FlasherData.Context;
using FlasherData.Repositories;
using FlasherData.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<FlasherContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FlasherDb")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

The old .NET 5 `Startup.cs` file that worked:

```
using FlasherData.Context;
using FlasherData.Repositories;
using FlasherData.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace FlasherData
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // SQLite connection and database context
            services.AddDbContext<FlasherContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FlasherDb")));

            // Dependency Injection
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }
    }
}
```

The .NET 5 library did not have a `Program.cs` file as it was not needed in a .NET 5 library project.

This is a link to the entire solution: [Flasher](https://github.com/tysongibby/Flasher)

Answer (score 1):

For those struggling with this make sure your `.csproj` `Output type` is set to `Console Application` (right-click your project and select properties).

If you prefer updating your `.csproj` manually you can simply add the tag  `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` inside the `<PropertyGroup>` tag.

E.g.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    .
    .
    .
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example you show isn't library code, but the entry point of an application. Top-level-statements are internally transformed into the `Main` method of the assembly, it's really just a syntactical alternative. But a library must not have a `Main` method, and that's why you get the mentioned error.

Therefore, for a library, either just remove the startup code or (to get the equivalent behavior than before) change it back to what it was before. There's no need to use top-level-statements anywhere. When updating an application from .NET 5.0 to .NET 6.0, typically you don't have to change anything (except in the project files), because the existing code base is fully backwards compatible.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and agree. However pre-.NET 6, I was able to have some "startup" code to initialize libraries so they could have necessary services for things like DbContext and Dependency Injection where needed.  If I can't do this in "Startup" code in the Program.cs file, where do I do it?

Comment: @TysonGibby I'm not really familiar with Web-type projects. But I would just do it exactly as you did before. What worked for a .NET 5.0 project should still work for .NET 6.0. They keep adding new features to the compiler, but they take it very seriously not to break existing ways of achieving something.

Comment: That is exactly the reason for my question. What I did before doesn't work. It gives the above indicated error "Program using top-level statements must be an executable".  I have not been able to find any documentation or direction on how it should be done in a .NET 6 library.

Comment: I think I found the answer. Implementing it to see if it works.